Granting Users Access to Burn to CD - Windows Server 2022
Having trouble allowing normal users to use the Burn to Disc function on Windows Server 2022.
It allows administrators to burn to disc if in the Regedit /HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Policies/System/
EnableLUA = 0
When I go on a normal user account the function is still not available.
users to have full control in the security tabs
Unfortunately it is a feature of the systems that will be used quite frequently so not something I can really ignore, even tho it is outdated.

Have you seen https://community.spiceworks.com/t/gpo-for-disabling-the-cd-rom-drive-from-being-opened/567511/2? Not sure if those keys are helpful.

Try to set NoCDBurninq to 1 as described here, and also the described Group Policy.
